# Which volatile ices are hardest below 100 K?

Tags: solid-state-physics, astronomy, simulations, cryogenics

In the context of planetary science,
some elements and compounds are informally called volatile instead of refractory,
such as
H<sub>2</sub>O, HCN, CO<sub>2</sub>, NH<sub>3</sub>, HCHO, CH<sub>4</sub>, CO, N<sub>2</sub>.

At conditions found near planetary surfaces in the solar system
(often much colder than Earth's),
when these are solid, which ones are **hardest** by a scale such as Vickers, Rockwell, Brinell, Mohs, Shore or Knoop?

Direct measurements seem [rare](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46953/1235).  We might need [*ab initio*](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2053-1591/aafae5) simulation.

Comment: I'm not sure why there'd be a need for ab initio simulation when it's easily possible to, say, chill water down to these temperatures, e.g. immerse regular ice in liquid nitrogen (77 K). One just needs access to the relevant equipment to run the experiments and procure the Numbers(tm).

Comment: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/2012JE004101 Might prove useful as a starting point to search